# Loop over result set and execute insert statement as part of a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure which can do the following, store result of following select query

Query #1:

```
SELECT ID  
FROM [DVMTO2APP].[Auth].[Principals] 
WHERE Name = 'manufacturing_system'` --> [5]
```

Query #2: inside a loop do this:

```
INSERT INTO [DVMTO2APP].[Auth].[PrincipalPermissions] (PrincipalID, PermissionID, isAllowed) 
VALUES (5, 1, 1)
```

Please note that `5` has to be obtained from step1 and feed into a loop for step 2.

Comment: Sounds great! Did you have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this not as simple as:

```
insert <permissions> (columns)
select ID, 1, 1 from <principals> where Name = 'manufacturing_system';
```

And for the sake of future generations, do **NOT** use three part names unless there is a really, really good reason to do so. The current database for the connection used to run this query should determine which database contains the specified tables. Otherwise, your code is far less portable and requires adjusting for different environments, migrations, etc.